# set of positive roots made negative by a Weyl group element

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $w$ is a Weyl group element of a simple lie algebra and the reduced expression for $w$ is $s_{i_1}s_{i_2}...s_{i_k}$ what are the positive roots (in terms of reflections from reduced expressions of $w$ applied to some simple roots) made negative by $w$ ?

Comment: Bourbaki, Groupes et Algebres de Lie, Ch VI, Section 1.6, Corollaire 2. (Or in many other texts on Lie theory).